# Ionic 2 Android release app not working

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, hybrid-mobile-app

I am facing a really weird problem with my APK release.

First ionic Deploy it's always undefined, it seems that is not injected.

Second, if I open and close the app several times I get a messages saying that cordova it's not loaded.

The most weird thing is that happens only with the android release, but it works perfectly with android debug.

Any help? Please? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

check your main actvity and xml are of same name and make sure that it has been declared in your manifest properly.

now 1. clean your project once

2. re-build your project
3. now generate your apk.

Answer (score 0):

Guys I found the issue.

If I run this command he apk works perfectly

`ionic build android --release`

but if I run

`ionic build android --release --prod`

the size of the apk it's different and gave me that problem.

Comment: if you have facing lots of problem back up your application and make application fresh I hove Your Problem is solved

Answer (score 0):

The problem for me seemed to be with the "pageName.component.ts" file that is created when you use the "ionic generate page" command.
Create your pages manually and run it (ionic run android --prod) or (ionic run android --prod) again.
it worked for me.
Home they fix it soon.